# Solution of IVP is defined for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ if $f$ is Lipschitz

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lipschitz-functions, initial-value-problems

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ a locally Lipschitz function such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$ with $x_1<x_2$. If $x_0\in(x_1,x_2)$, then the solution of the IVP $$x'=f(x),\;x(0)=x_0$$ is defined for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

If one look at the phase plane it makes sense, but I don't know how to start the proof, I think it involves Picard–Lindelöf theorem. Any hint?

Comment: The idea is that, once $x(t)$ hits $x_1$ or $x_2$, it will stay there for all time. Otherwise, $x(t)$ stays inside $[x_1, x_2]$, on which $f'$ is bounded...